# Time complexity of recursive call inside 2 for loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

```js
int maxProfit(int price[], int start, int end) 
{ 
  
    // If the stocks can't be bought 
    if (end <= start) 
        return 0; 
  
    // Initialise the profit 
    int profit = 0; 
  
    // The day at which the stock 
    // must be bought 
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
  
        // The day at which the 
        // stock must be sold 
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= end; j++) { 
  
            // If byuing the stock at ith day and 
            // selling it at jth day is profitable 
            if (price[j] > price[i]) { 
  
                // Update the current profit 
                int curr_profit = price[j] - price[i] 
                                  + maxProfit(price, start, i - 1) 
                                  + maxProfit(price, j + 1, end); 
  
                // Update the maximum profit so far 
                profit = max(profit, curr_profit); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return profit; 
}
```

What is the time complexity of maxProfit ?

According to me, recurrence relation is :

```
T(0,n) = n^2*(T(0,i) +  T(j,n))
```

After this, How to solve this 2 variable recurrence relation ?

Comment: Actually, it looks like `n^2*(T(0,i) + T(j,n))` since the recursion occurs inside the loops

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you try to achieve because this will take forever and is most likely not necessary..

Comment: I agree with @Aldert The whole thing could probably be reduced to `maxprofit=0; for(i=1; i<n;i++) if(a[i-1]<a[i]) maxprofit+=a[i]-a[i-1]` and run in O(n)

Comment: @Aldert I know that this problem has a O(n) solution, but I was curious to compute the time complexity of this approach.

Comment: The recurrence relation is not T(0, n) = n^2*(T(0, i) + T(j, n)). That has two free variables i and j in, so should presumably be summed, but the n^2 already assumes a sum. The recurrence relation is something like T(n) = sum(T(i-1) + T(n-j-1) for 0 <= i < j <= n). Solving looks feasible (start by counting how many T(k) there are for each k in the sum), and then doing something like looking at T(n+1) - T(n), but it'll be some work and perhaps only educational to the person solving given the algorithm is not great.

Answer (score -2):

nested loop means n<sup>2</sup> and if you calculate the two recursive equation then you find:

1. the first recursive relation if n = 5 then it's gonna run 1,2,3,4
   times. So, T(n) = T(1)+T(2)+T(3)+....+T(n-1)
2. the second recursive relation if n = 5 then it's gonna run 4,3,2,1
   times. So, T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2)+.....+T(1)

so T(n) = n<sup>2</sup>{ T(n-1)+T(n-1) }
= n<sup>2</sup>{ 2T(n-1)} for {2T(n-1)} the complexity is O(2<sup>n</sup>) and now multiply it by n<sup>2</sup> but since n<sup>2</sup> is much smaller than 2<sup>n</sup> so we ignore them and complexity stands: O(2<sup>n</sup>)

Comment: This answer uses informal rules for computing complexities (nested loops are n^2, you can ignore small terms), but unfortunately goes into territories where these informal rules (which are usually applicable in certain common situations) just don't apply. For example T(n) = 2(n^2)T(n-1)  solves exactly to 2^n(n!)^2 which grows hugely faster than O(2^n).